# Highcharts: Custom tooltip

Tags: highcharts, tooltip

yet another question: I have a stacked bar chart with categorized y-axis and I would like to have custom tooltips on each of the bars. But so far I cannot figure out how to address the individual category correctly. The tooltip formatter code I use works, but I cannot access the individual category. Can anyone help?

This is the code:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    colors: ['#c83f3f', '#66b257'],    
        xAxis: {
            labels: {
            style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontSize: '12px',
            fontFamily: 'Merriweather Sans, sans-serif',
          }
        },
        categories: ['<a href="https://www.testlink.com">Testlink Nummer 1</a>', '<a href="https://www.testlink.com">Objektname 2</a>', '<a href="https://www.testlink.com">Die Nummer 3</a>', '<a href="https://www.testlink.com">Test 4</a>', '<a href="https://www.testlink.com">Test 5</a>', '<a href="https://www.testlink.com">Test 6</a>', '<a href="https://www.testlink.com">Test 7</a>', '<a href="https://www.testlink.com">Test</a>']
    },
    tooltip : {
        formatter: function() {
            var tooltip;
            if (this.series == '1') {
                tooltip = '<b>Final result is </b> ' + this.y;
            }
            else {
                tooltip =  '<span style="color:' + this.series.color + '">' + this.series.name + '</span>: <b>' + this.y + '</b><br/>';
            }
            return tooltip;
        }
    },   
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        labels: {
            style: {
            fontWeight: 'normal',
            fontFamily: 'Merriweather Sans, sans-serif',
          }
        },
    },
    legend: {
        reversed: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            groupPadding: 1,
            pointWidth: 35,
        }
    },
    credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
    series: [{
        name: 'Nicht erfüllte Kriterien',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2, 6, 4, 5]
    }, {
        name: 'Erfüllte Kriterien',
        data: [5, 7, 6, 3, 8, 4, 6, 5]
    }]
});
```

Thanks a lot!
- Oliver

Comment: what do you mean by `if (this.series == '1') {..}` in tooltip formatter.

Comment: Can you explain in more details what you try to achieve? You can access category by point.category (this.category).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I am trying to show individual tooltips for each of the categories in the chart. That tooltip shall not only contain the name of the category, but also some text in HTML which I would like to set manually for each category.